# Screen Tearing issues on Ubuntu 18.04 with Nvidia GeForceGT710 driven by Nouveau driver

Tags: screen, tearing

I have a severe screen tearing problem. I am using the open source Nouveau drivers instead of the proprietary nvidia drivers. When I apply the Nvidia drivers Ubuntu does not boot. Nouveau drivers do not have any issue except for Screen tearing. 
My system is
Ubuntu 18.04 with Liquorix kernel 
Intel Core i3 with 550@3.20Ghz *4
Nvidia GeForce GT710 Graphics card. 
Please help.

Comment: Try using wayland (select at the little gear icon on the login page).  That will use the internal GPU instead of the Nvidia GPU, and avoid the synchronization issue (scan this site for "tearing" for lots of questions on this topic).

Comment: Thank you. I have moved out of liquorix kernel and installed the generic kernel along with nvidia proprietary driver. The screen tearing went away.